# How do you troubleshoot cruise control? (Mazda Tribute 2005)

Tags: troubleshooting, mazda, cruise-control

I just bought a used 2005 Mazda Tribute. The only problem I have with the car is that the cruise control doesn't work....and I have no clue how/where to start!

The cruise light on the dashboard doesn't come on when I turn the cruise system on. I don't think it's just a bulb, because the cruise system doesn't work at all.

I suppose it could be the switch itself....but how would I go about testing that?
Is there a fuse specific to CC? I don't have any other dashboard lights out or anything like that.

Thanks for your help in pointing me in the right direction!
Matthew

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be anywhere between the button, and the module. The first step should be to read the codes, and ensure nothing is calling for a fault. The next step, if no codes are found, is to check the switch. The reality is that troubleshooting this at home can be difficult without the proper equipment. This list of [Mazda OBD-II Trouble Codes](http://www.obd-codes.com/trouble_codes/mazda/) does not show any cruise control ones, so you might have to get a Mazda code reader (or one equipped to read Mazda codes) to accomplish this job. Make sure to check all things are tight as far as you can tell, but otherwise I recommend starting with the codes.

Comment: There's my ignorance - I hadn't even thought about a code reader. In my mind codes only exist when there's an angry check engine light on. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Matthew No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the information...Here's what I learned:

1. The recall was issued after my issue -- it created a potential stuck throttle situation. Different problem that affects the same system.
2. I verified that the switch under the brake moved freely.
3. I verified that no fuses (particularly brake light fuse or computer fuses) were bad.
4. No codes made it to the OBD reader to test.

I finally broke down and went to the dealer. After an hour of troubleshooting, they determined the 'controller' module was bad. Required a replacement. FWIW, the replacement module required programming when it arrived as well. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Throttle cable was recalled sometimes sticks and dealer is supposed to replace and not charge. Call your dealer to find out about recall of part.

Comment: Would be helpfull to add a little more information about the recall. Maybe a link to a [pdf](http://www-odi.nhtsa.dot.gov/acms/cs/jaxrs/download/doc/UCM424183/RCDNN-12V357-2973.pdf) version of it?.